# WordPress user's role set to "no role for this site" when emember subscription expires

Tags: php, wordpress

EMember version: **7.5.3**

WordPress Version: **3.4.2**

**EMember Settings**:

- Allow Expired Account login:: **checked**
- Automatically Create Wordpress User: **checked**
- Automatically log into Wordpress: **checked**
- Automatically log into eMember: **checked**

Scenario:

1. User registers as a subscriber.
2. Logins successfully to WordPress wp-admin.
3. Account expires after a day.
4. User tries to login to wp-admin.
5. User is redirected to "You do not have sufficient permissions to
   access this page." page.
6. Admin checks user's details in User administration page.
7. **Role** is set to **- No role for this site -**

**Role** should still be set to **subscriber**.
What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: This question could be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

- Open file manager from your cpanel
- Find `WWW` folder under root directory, then click on `wp-content` and under that, click on the `plugin` folder and browse the plugin you recently installed and delete only that new installed plugin folder (for example you should be in `www/wp-content/plugins/`).
- Go to your internet explorer and login to your site with your wordpress login details. It should work as it worked for me. I had installed an audio plugin and the wordpress gave me the following error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

So, I deleted the plugin and the problem was solved.

Comment: Did not solve my problem. I deleted all plugins already except for eMember. Nothing happened. Still encountered "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" on login

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that when user membership expires they are removed from the role by emembership plugin however there is no other role to go in. you can create another role unsubscribed and movethem in there. check within emembership docs how to do this.